# NSMutableDictionary class attribute is not modified in method

Tags: objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

Having following class with NSMutableDictionary* property

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
@property(retain,atomic) NSMutableDictionary* dict;
- (void) method;
@end

- (id) init{
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
        self.dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    }

    return self;
}
- (void) method
{
    NSMutableDictionary*  dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    self.dict[@"Test"] = @"Shmest";
    dict[@"Test"] = @"Shmest";
    NSLog(@"Count: %ld",[self.dict allKeys].count);
    NSLog(@"Count: %ld",[dict allKeys].count);
}
```

The output is

```
2014-02-23 19:05:44.110 MyProj[12818:303] Count: 0
2014-02-23 19:05:44.110 MyProj[12818:303] Count: 1
```

Why self.dict is not modified?

**UPD**
Used `MyClass * obj = [MyClass alloc]` instead of `MyClass * obj = [[MyClass alloc] init]`, so `init` has not been called.

Comment: Are you setting self.dict anywhere? Before you set a value to the dict property it will be nil, thus behave like it is in your code.

Comment: I'm setting it in init method (added to post body)

Comment: Add `NSLog(dict)` to `method` to check that to is initialized.

Comment: It was not initialized, my bad. Used `MyClass * obj = [MyClass alloc]` instead of `MyClass * obj = [[MyClass alloc] init]`;
Many thanks!
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is necessary to instantiate the `dict` property, this can be done in the `init` method.

Sample:

```
- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _dict = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Call with:

```
MyClass *myClass = [MyClass new];
[myClass method];
```

Comment: Please, take a look at `init` method I've added to post. Is there something wrong? (`new`, `dictionary`, and `alloc` behave in the same way: new value is not added to dict)

Comment: I just tested your code and it works. I did have to add `@implementation MyClass` and the ending `@end`.